# Extracting a value from Scala map of type Map[String,Any], where Any can be a Map itself

Tags: java, scala, dictionary, jvm

I have a scala method like :

```
import collection.JavaConversions._ 

def foo(message: Map[String, Any]) {

  // message is implicitly converted to Java format
  someJavaApi.method1(message)

  message.get("mapField") match {
    case Some(mapField) => 
      val stringValue = mapField.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]].get("internalField")
      otherJavaApi.method(stringValue)
    case None => /* do something */
  }
}
```

where message is a map with structure like:

```
Map(
   "field" -> "value",
   "mapField"-> Map("internalField"->"someValue")
)
```

As obvious from above code,I am interested in extracting the "someValue" from the "mapField" dictionary object's "internalField"

But I keep getting an error at run time like:

```
scala.collection.JavaConversions$JMapWrapper cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map
```

Which I feel is due to implicit conversion from scala to java collections on call to first java library API, but I am not sure about that, I would like a suggestion on how I can improve the extraction of the String value "someValue" from the "mapField", in more functional or Scala-ish way and avoid exceptions.

I am using scala 2.9.2 version.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking here - it would help if you could provide compilable example code.

Comment: Just say "no!!!" to `Map[String, Any]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java maps are mutable and therefore their Scala wrappers are mutable.Map, not immutable.Map.

```
scala> Map("field" -> "value","mapField"-> Map("internalField"->"someValue"))
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Object] = Map(field -> value, mapField -> Map(internalField -> someValue))

scala> import collection.JavaConverters._
import collection.JavaConverters._

scala> res0.mapValues { case m: Map[_,_] => m.asJava case x => x }
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Object] = Map(field -> value, mapField -> {internalField=someValue})

scala> res0.asJava
res3: java.util.Map[String,Object] = {field=value, mapField=Map(internalField -> someValue)}

scala> .asScala
res4: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Object] = Map(field -> value, mapField -> Map(internalField -> someValue))

scala> .foreach { case (k, v: collection.Map[_,_]) => println(v.toList) case _ =>  }
List((internalField,someValue))
```

Some help with safety:

```
scala> :edit res0
+Map("field" -> Left("value"),"mapField"-> Right(Map("internalField"->"someValue")))
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]]] = Map(field -> Left(value), mapField -> Right(Map(internalField -> someValue)))

scala> .mapValues { case Left(s) => s.length case Right(m) => m.values.map(_.length).sum }
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(field -> 5, mapField -> 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make a working example from your code:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._

object Test extends App {

  object someJavaApi {
    def method1(message: java.util.Map[_, _]) { }
  }

  object otherJavaApi {
    def method(s: String) { }
  }

  def foo(message: Map[String, Any]) {

    // message is implicitly converted to Java format
    someJavaApi.method1(message)

    message.get("mapField") match {
      case Some(mapField) =>
        val stringValue = mapField.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]("internalField")
        otherJavaApi.method(stringValue)
      case None => /* do something */
    }
  }

  val message = Map(
    "field" -> "value",
    "mapField" -> Map("internalField" -> "someValue")
  )

  foo(message)

}
```

That runs without error.

But I don't know how this question can be answered without compiling code to work from.